# converting inner values to integer of a list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

After process the values from a `stdin` I got the following list in my python program:

```
[['92', '022'], ['82', '12'], ['77', '13']]
```

I am trying to have the values as:

```
[[92, 22], [82, 12], [77, 13]]
```

I have tried to `map` the values but found error:

```
print map(int, s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lenovo-pc/PycharmProjects/untitled11/order string.py", line 13, in <module>
    print map(int, s)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Where `s` is my list.

Kindly, suggest me what is the optimized way to make the list of str to convert into integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `list comprehension`:

```
>>> [ list(map(int,ele)) for ele in l ]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : l = [['92', '022'], ['82', '12'], ['77', '13']]
OUT : [[92, 22], [82, 12], [77, 13]]
```

---

The error :

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

is thrown since the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function takes in a flat iterable or list / 1D list in a loose sense. Since you are sending it a multi-dimensional list, it iterates over the sub-list and tries to apply the function on them and hence throws the error.

> `map(function, iterable, ...)`
>
> The iterable arguments may be a sequence or any iterable object;  the result is always a list.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for thank you. I will accept after 12 minutes... :P

Comment: @JafferWilson : hahaha. Glad to help.

Comment: Might be worth adding a line explaining what the problem was and how it was solved? (namely, with a two dimensional list, `map(int,s)` was sending the sublists, not values, to `int()`

Comment: @ArthurSpoon : doing the edit at the moment. Was googling references to add.